# what does ReplicaFetcherManager does in kafka and when are ReplicaFetcherThread started started/shutdown?

Tags: apache-kafka

Can someone explain what does ReplicaFetcherManager do in kafka and what is ReplicaFetcherThread when is this created and destoryed.

Comment: ReplicaFetcherManager coordinates how data is replicated between brokers. It's basically managing the ReplicaFetcherThreads that do the actual copying of data to keep replicas in sync.